# Why is my gas dryer's thermal fuse repeatedly blowing?

Tags: appliances

I have a Maytag centennial gas dryer. One day I found that the thermal fuse had blown out. I replaced the thermal fuse, but when I tried to turn it on it sparked then blew again. Why would this happen? Should I give up and get a new dryer? I did clean out the vents and then ran it before reattaching the vent to the outside.

Comment: If it blew instantly the problem is probably not related to the fuse. You do mean *thermal fuse* as in the type that is tripped by heat right? I agree with DrMoishe's assessment.

Comment: The thermal fuse trips because the thermostat is bad.   Buy both pieces and replace at the same time.  If you can't read the wiring diagram to figure out what is what in there (which is located on a piece of paper INSIDE YOUR DRYER -- Yes it's there taped inside the head/control area)  then CALL A PROFESSIONAL.

Comment: @KyleB Not necessarily. My thermal fuse (electric dryer, but they all have thermal fuses because they all produce a lot of heat that causes problems if it gets to the wrong place) went a few years ago. I did a thorough cleaning of the dryer and replaced the fuse and fine ever since. I did *not* change the thermostat.

Comment: Need some clarification "sparked then blew again" - how long was it running when it blew again? Were the sparks at the thermal fuse or someplace else? How did you know it was the thermal fuse in the first place - did you verify continuity (or lack thereof)?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Of course no advice can be 100%.   OP said he cleaned the vents and changed the fuse, same thing happened.  So he's gotta figure out why.  In your case it was clogged vents.  His aren't.  So what else could it be?   Those thermomstats fail so often they sell the fuse & thermostat as a matched set....   OP has a gas dryer BTW.   If that doesn't fix it, and he is unable to perform actual troubleshooting, it's service-tech time.

Answer (score 1):

> I replaced the thermal fuse, but when I tried to turn it on it sparked then blew again. Why would this happen?

Fuses are meant to prevent fires in case of a malfunction.
You replaced the fuse without adressing the malfunction.
The fuse is just doing it's job again.

> Should I give up and get a new dryer?

You can also hire a repair technician, if that makes economic sense for the unit.

But I'd recommend a heatpump dryer to save on your energy bills, in exchange for some longer drying time.